# Does LINQ do short-circuit evaluation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, linq, null, short-circuiting

We had a `Nullable object must have a value` error today on this line of code:

```
list = From x In Me Where x.FooDate.HasValue AndAlso x.FooDate.Value.Date >= barDate
```

Funny thing is that I feel sure this used to work fine (and there has always been a sprinkling of null values in the underlying data). And logically it looks fine to me. The check for `HasValue` and the `AndAlso` *look* as if they're going to shield us from any Null danger.

But it seems suddenly they're not. Am I missing something?

OK, we can correct it to this, which eliminates the error:

```
list = From x In Me Where If(x.FooDate.HasValue, x.FooDate.Value.Date >= barDate,False)
```

But this looks to me less readable. Any thoughts?

**Update ... and Confession**:
In simplifying the above code to shorten the line I left out a crucial chunk of the code. The original problem should have read something like:

```
list = From x In Me Where x.FooDate.HasValue AndAlso x.FooDate.Value.Date >= fromDate And x.FooDate.Value.Date <= toDate
```

Because of the rules of shortcircuiting and operator precedence (as [outlined in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3677979/180430) to a long ago question of my own) I needed to add brackets round the second part of the instruction in order to stop LINQ evaluating the second `x.FooDate.Value.Date`:

```
list = From x In Me Where x.FooDate.HasValue AndAlso (x.FooDate.Value.Date >= fromDate and x.FooDate.Value.Date <= toDate)
```

Thanks to both answers for throwing up quick test code to verify that LINQ really does obey AndAlso and force me to look more closely at the original problem.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with sample data and show us this code?

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects, or are you using some other LINQ provider? Also, can you include the entire LINQ query? You appear to at least be missing the Select portion

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, or is Me returning something strange (that isn't IEnumerable, for instance)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter just coming back to this, i see that you've provided a simplified sample so I'll try yours ... thanks

Comment: This is LINQ to Objects I guess (the only kind I've used), where Me is a BindingList(Of Foo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your query is safe, at least following sample code is:

```
Dim dateList As New List(Of Nullable(Of Date))
For i As Int32 = 0 To 12
    If (i Mod 3 = 0) Then
        dateList.Add(Nothing)
    Else
        dateList.Add(New Date(2012, i, 1))
    End If
Next
Dim july = New Date(2012, 7, 1)
Dim fromJuly = (From m In dateList
      Where m.HasValue AndAlso m.Value.Date >= july).ToList
```

<sub>Note: If i would replace `AndAlso` with `And` i would get your exception.</sub>

So the problem must be somewhere else. Show us more of your class please.

Comment: i've run your code and got the same results as you so you're right the problem must be elsewhere. i'll keep digging

Comment: @hawbsl: Instead of adding brackets on your second condition, why don't you simply use `AndAlso` instead of `And`? Or have i misunderstood the "operator precedence"-issue?

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I wrote this code, and it works for me fine, even with `barDate` set to `Nothing`.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim barDate As Nullable(Of DateTime) = Nothing

    Dim List = From x In GetDates() Where x.FooDate.HasValue AndAlso x.FooDate.Value.Date > barDate

    Console.WriteLine(List.Count())

End Sub

Function GetDates() As List(Of Foo)
    Dim l = New List(Of Foo)
    l.Add(New Foo With {.FooDate = DateTime.Now})
    l.Add(New Foo)
    Return l
End Function

Class Foo
    Private m_fooDate As DateTime?
    Public Property FooDate() As DateTime?
        Get
            Return m_fooDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTime?)
            m_fooDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```